# How can i make the accelerometer from iphone to work in background?

Tags: iphone, accelerometer

If i set the playing loop sound and is working correctly in background. How can i get data from accelerometer when the app is in background?

Comment: How about using more clear language?

Answer (score 2):

Audio services, location services and VoIP services can be used in the background. Accelerometer can not.